# How to input text from edit text in json array

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

i'm new to android json and just starting working on it as in place of sqllite databse ,

i want user to input data into edit text and it go and save into the json array like we use to do in the sqllite databse by table

```
    queryValues.put("studentid", studentId);
    queryValues.put("roll", roll.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("name", name.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("class", Class.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("marks", marks.getText().toString());
    data.updatestudent(queryValues);
```

**so is there any way that we can make user to input data from edit text and then it go save into json Array and  also user can do update and delete operations.**

or if there is anyother way , guide me into that direction .
Also i can't find any good example of json .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

Before you make a call to the below function, make sure that your edit text does not return null. Use basic validations.

```
 public JSONArray makeJSON() {
        JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        try {

            jObj.put("customer_name", edittex1.getText().toString);
            jObj.put("serial_number",  edittex2.getText().toString);
            jObj.put("membership_number",  edittex3.getText().toString);
            jObj.put("brand_name",  edittex4.getText().toString);
            jObj.put("model_number",  edittex5.getText().toString);
            jObj.put("IMEI_number",  edittex6.getText().toString);
            jObj.put("handset_purchase", edittex7.getText().toString);
            jObj.put("counter_name",  edittex8.getText().toString);


            jArr.put(jObj);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
        }


        return jArr;
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but after viewing it from button , if i enter the values again from edit text does it replace the previous values  or create another file to store those .

Comment: Yes you have to call this function on buton click and you are done - whatever the values be in your edit text boxes will be copied afresh to the array

Comment: Sorry although - This is not a file but a JSON Array.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can ,
on button click you have to retrieve all values from editext ,
make a jsonobject like that

```
JSONObject student1 = new JSONObject();
try {
    student1.put("id", "3");
    student1.put("name", "NAME OF STUDENT");
    student1.put("year", "3rd");
    student1.put("curriculum", "Arts");
    student1.put("birthday", "5/5/1993");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```